# React component getting wrong value from a wrong field field in the state object when I use "defaultValue" to assign values

Tags: reactjs

My code is as follows, and you can see how it works in https://codepen.io/rongeegee/pen/BaVJjGO:

```
const { useState } = React;

const Counter = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    displayData: "data_one",
    data_one: {
      text: ""
    },
    data_two:{
      text:""
    }
  })
  
  function handleOnChange(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const new_data = {...data};
    if (event.target.name == "displayData"){
      new_data.displayData = event.target.value;
      setData(new_data);
    }
    else{
      new_data[event.target.name]["text"] = event.target.value;]
      setData(new_data);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onChange={handleOnChange}>
        <select name="displayData" value={data.displayData}>
          <option value="data_one">data_one</option>
          <option value="data_two">data_two</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        {
          data.displayData == "data_one" 
            ?
            <>data One: <input name="data_one" defaultValue={data.data_one.text} /></> 
            :
            <>data two: <input name="data_two" defaultValue={data.data_two.text} /></>
        }
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

If I type something in the input of data_one, toggle between the values between "data_one" and "data_two", the data_two input field will have the same value inside. If I change the value in data_one toggle the dropdown to "data_one", data_one will have the same value again.

This shouldn't happen since data_one input uses the value of the text field in data_one field in the data state while data_two input uses the one in data_two field. One should not take the value from another field in the state.

Comment: You are cloning the object only shallowly. Which causes you to modify the data directly

Comment: @KonradLinkowski even if I clone the object shallowly, I only modify one field, why does it modify the other field too?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the reason to why your code doesn't do what you want, but you are aware, that you only change your state when switching between the data (not when typing something into the input field)? You are manipulating State without actually setting it with the provided callback. This can potentially lead to big problems.

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII What you said about me not changing my state when typing into the input field is not true. in the else statement of my handleOnChange method, I do change the state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React has a way to determine if/which elements/components have changed and which haven't. This is neccesary, because DOM manipulation is expensive, so we should try to limit it as much as possible. That's why React has a way to determine what changed between rerenders and what didn't; and only changes what changed in the DOM.

So if we in your case swith from dataOne to dataTwo, React goes something like: "Oh nice `input` element stays `input` element. Nice I don't have to completely destroy that DOM node and render it rom scratch, I can just check what changed and change that. Let's see: The name has changed ... so let's change that, but apart from that everything stayed the same." (This means your input element won't get destroyed and the other one initialy rendered, but the one input element get's a name change and React calls it a day - and since `default Value` only works on initial creation of an element/DOM node, it won't be shown)

The way React rerenders stuff and compares/modifies the DOM is quite complicated. For futher information I can recomend the following video: https://youtu.be/i793Qm6kv3U (It really helped me understand the whole React Render process way better).

A possible fix to your problem, would be to give each input element a key. So your input elements could look something like:

```
<input key="1" name="data_one" defaultValue={data.data_one.text} />
<input key="2" name="data_two" defaultValue={data.data_two.text} />
```

So yeah, the fix is fairly easy; understanding the reason to why we need this fix however is everything but easy.

Answer (score 0):

regarding your comment (my answer would be to long for a comment, and formatting is nicer in an answer)

nope you aren't changing state on input-field change ... you are changing/manipulating the state variable `data` ... but you are not updating your state. Hence no rerender gets triggered, and in case of a rerender triggered by something else the data will be lost. So you aren't actually changing state.

Changes to your state can only be made by calling the callback Funcnction provided by the useState-Hook. (In your case the callback provided by the useState-Hook is `setData`. In your `else` statement you are not calling the provided callback, just manipulating the `data` object (since you shallow clone and therefor manipulate the original `data` object)

When changing state ALWAYS use the provided callback `const [stateVariable, thisIsTheCallback] = useState(initVal)`. If you don't use this callback and just manipulate the stateVariable you will sooner or later run into problems (and debugging that issue is particularly tedious, since it seems like you are changing state (because the stateVariable changes) but you aren't changing state since only the callback can do this)

Comment: Thank you. But I just edited the question. It was a negligence and I missed that line that call setData. Even if I do so, the problem in the input doesn't get updated still persist. Please take a look.

Comment: @Rongeegee my other answer has a fix (and explanation) to your problem

Answer (score 0):

In place of `defaultValue` attribute to your `<input/>` replace that with `value` attribute and everything will work.

And to know why `defaultValue` won't get updated after state change,  read the **first answer by @Lord-JulianXLII**